# ntdll function forward declaration

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

While trying to implement some sample code I found, I hit an error that I can't quite understand the cause of it. So here it goes.

In the header, I saw it declares something something like this. However, when I tried to compile it, VS gives me an error with this "unresolved external symbol...".

```
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtOpenSection(
    OUT PHANDLE             SectionHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK          DesiredAccess,
    IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   ObjectAttributes
);
```

However, When I change it to something like this, I don't see the error anymore.

```
NTSTATUS(NTAPI *NtOpenSection)(
   OUT PHANDLE              SectionHandle,
   IN ACCESS_MASK           DesiredAccess,
   IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES    ObjectAttributes
);
```

I'm not entirely sure what is causing it. It will be great if someone post some online references as well for me to understand more.

Comment: if first case you declare **external** symbol `__imp_NtOpenSection` (or `__imp__NtOpenSection@12` for *x86*). when linker link - he not found implementation of this and say "unresolved external symbol...". solution - add `ntdll.lib` to linker input. in second case - you declare and **implement** variable `NtOpenSection`.this is not external symbol, so and no any linker errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need understand how compiler and linker work. compiler create [*Common Object File Format (COFF)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#coff_symbol_table) files(s). here exist [*COFF Symbol Table*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#coff_symbol_table) for every symbol declared in source file. in binary form it implemented as [`IMAGE_SYMBOL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/symbols) (looking in `winnt.h` or `ntimage.h`). here most interesting for us is *Section Number Values* (`SHORT   SectionNumber;`). in general words - symbol can be **Defined** – Symbols that have been created and assigned storage addresses and space within the file. (one-based index into the section table) or **Undefined** – Symbols that have been referenced in a file but have not been assigned a storage address.

> `IMAGE_SYM_UNDEFINED` - *The symbol record is not yet assigned a
>   section. A value of zero indicates that a reference to an external
>   symbol is defined elsewhere. A value of non-zero is a common symbol
>   with a size that is specified by the value.*

when you use

```
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtOpenSection(
    OUT PHANDLE             SectionHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK          DesiredAccess,
    IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   ObjectAttributes
);
```

compiler create `__imp_NtOpenSection` (x64, arm, arm64) or `__imp__NtOpenSection@12` (x86) symbol with `IMAGE_SYM_UNDEFINED` section value - really you here **declare** function, but you **not implement** it. this function (`NtOpenSection`)must be defined (implemented) elsewhere. when linker link - it search it implementation (`__imp_NtOpenSection` symbol) in all obj and lib files, which is passed to him as input. if it can not found implementation of it - `IMAGE_SYMBOL` record with one-based index into the section table - he say - unresolved external symbol. so you must or implement function (symbol) yourself, or give to linker lib or obj file, where this function is implemented. in case user mode, it implemented in `ntdll.lib` or `ntdllp.lib`. so you and need pass one of this lib files to linker input - this resolve error.

in second case

```
NTSTATUS(NTAPI *NtOpenSection)(
   OUT PHANDLE              SectionHandle,
   IN ACCESS_MASK           DesiredAccess,
   IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES    ObjectAttributes
);
```

you declare and **implement** variable. it already have been created and assigned storage addresses and space within the file. as result no any unresolved externals here.

also read [Symbol Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3677/chapter2-14824/index.html) for better understand this process.

also i suggest - compile your c/c++ file without [`/GL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization) option (*Only the `/HEADERS` DUMPBIN option is available for use on files produced with the `/GL` compiler option.* ) and run

```
link.exe /dump /symbols your.obj > some.txt
```

and look for `NtOpenSection` here:

```
00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp_NtOpenSection
```

in first case and

```
00000000 SECT4  notype       External     | ?NtOpenSection@@3P6AJPEAPEAXKPEAUOBJECT_ATTRIBUTES@@@ZEA (long (__cdecl* NtOpenSection)(void * *,unsigned long,struct OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES *))
```

in second case.

**`UNDEF`**  vs **`SECTx`**

---

from binary view in both case you declare pointer size (4 or 8 bytes) variable (`__imp_NtOpenSection` or `?NtOpenSection@@...`) which will be hold address to function. in both case indirect call on binary level will be **the same** :

`call [__imp_NtOpenSection]` or `call [?NtOpenSection@@...]`. different - in `__imp_` case - address of this variable (`__imp_NtOpenSection`) will be written in PE structures `Import Lookup Table` and it will be placed in `Import Address Table`. as result - loader (code in ntdll) will automatic resolve address or `NtOpenSection` and store this address in `__imp_NtOpenSection` variable. or fail load your PE, if address will be not resolved. so when your code begin executed - inside `__imp_NtOpenSection` already will be valid address of `NtOpenSection` function and you can just use it - call `NtOpenSection` from c/c++ code or `call [__imp_NtOpenSection]` from asm.

in second case (`?NtOpenSection@@...` or `[_]NtOpenSection` if you declare it with `extern "C"` or from c code, `_` for x86 only) - this will be simply variable. and when you code begin execute - here will be 0 (if you declare it as global/static) or undefined value (local variable in stack). before call `NtOpenSection` via such variable, you need first init it - assign real address of `NtOpenSection`. say as `*(void**)&NtOpenSection = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "NtOpenSection");`. after this you can use it. and how i say - will be no any different in call `NtOpenSection` via #1 or #2 declaration - code will be absolute the same